# CruiseControl.NET hangs on git-submodule bad file descriptor with TFS

Tags: git, tfs, cruisecontrol.net

I have a problem fetching submodules in git with CruiseControl.NET 1.8.5 version. I just updated to msysgit 64bit v2.5.0 and changed the config to use the new version.

```
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: line 535: 0: Bad file descriptor
. Process command: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe submodule foreach --recursive "git clean -d -f -x"
  bei ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ProcessSourceControl.Execute(ProcessInfo processInfo)
  bei ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Git.GitClean(IIntegrationResult result)
  bei ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Build(IIntegrationResult result)
  bei ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
```

If I change the project config to

```
<sourcecontrol type="git">
  <repository>$(tfsServerPath)/softwarename</repository>
  <branch>$(dev)</branch>
  <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
  <fetchSubmodules>false</fetchSubmodules>
  ...
</sourceControl>
```

it works for projects without submodules of course. What what could possibly go wrong here?

Kind Regards

Comment: I'm getting the same issue today. Using git 2.8.2

Comment: Update to 2.9.2 also didn't solve the problem

Comment: Still the same with bitbucket and 2.11.0

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround:

```
<sourcecontrol type="multi">
  <sourceControls>
    <git>
      <workingDirectory>src_dir</workingDirectory>         
    </git>
  </sourceControls>
</sourcecontrol>

<tasks>
  <exec>
    <executable>git</executable>
    <buildArgs>submodule init</buildArgs>
    <baseDirectory>src_dir</baseDirectory>
  </exec>
  <exec>
    <executable>git</executable>
    <buildArgs>submodule update</buildArgs>
    <baseDirectory>src_dir</baseDirectory>
  </exec>
</tasks>
```